# Realtime mesh deformation of soft objects

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d, mesh

My problem is simulation of soft object deformation on user interaction, like when you touch ball with sand inside it deformes its edges in spots you press on ball. How can I achieve it in Unity3D?

Comment: mesh deformation by accessing the mesh vertices and modifying them in cs script or shader. Question is too broad and maybe too advanced (dunno coding skills).

Comment: @Everts yeah, I can do it manually, but I need realistic deformations maybe using Poisson's ratio

Comment: So are you looking for the equation or the process?

Comment: @Everts some code examples how to implement it in Unity, maybe prefabs

Comment: Unfortunately, you somehow fall in the bucket of "Please code it for me". Your best shot is to look for tutorials online.

Comment: @Everts i could not find appropriate tutorials, so trying to get direction from people who maybe did something similar

Answer (score 1):

Soft body dynamics is a very complex topic, which is why most physics engines constrain themselves to rigid body dynamics. I am pretty sure that no one on StackOverflow is going to code this for you. There are some commercial solutions for Unity though, [Obi Softbody](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/physics/obi-softbody-130029) and [Truss Physics](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/truss-physics-41801) to list a couple.

Here is a cheaper but probably less feature complete option:

https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/physics/b-soft-body-deformation-53378

There are many different ways for simulating soft body physics, one common way is to map the vertices to a lattice of points (with some weight), and then simulate spring contraints between the lattice points. These types of lattices are probably best simulated with verlet integration.

[Here](http://www.alecrivers.com/fastlsm/) is a research paper on lattice shape matching.
[Here](http://www.ep.liu.se/ecp/010/007/ecp01007.pdf) is another paper on pressure models.

Comment: Thank you! Currently I am trying to work with Nvidia Flex, seems enough for me